# Need help in understanding Dist and DistArray

Tags: x10-language

I don't understand the following piece of code.

```
val array = new Array[INT](1..1000, ([i]:Point) => 0);
val dist = Dist.makeBlock(array.region);
val distArray = DistArray.make(dist, ([i]:Point) => array(i));
```

This is all. The expressions in () are very confusing, but also the =>, Dist and DistArray.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Array initializers like `([i]:Point) => 0` are *function literals* (also called closures), and are described in section 10.3 of the [X10 language specification](http://x10.sourceforge.net/documentation/languagespec/x10-latest.pdf).  `Dist` and `DistArray` support a flexible mapping of multidimensional regions to distributed data; these classes are described in Chapter 16 of the spec.